# Prolific USB to serial communication port

Tags: windows-10, usb

The Prolific USB-to-serial communication port is showing a warning:

> This device cannot start. (Code 10)
>
> A device which does not exist was specified.

I have tried to install the pl2303_64bit_installer, but I am don't have Internet access.

How do I make the connection of the Prolific USB-to-serial communication port without access to the Internet?

Platform: Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit.

Comment: Yep, I got that problem as well when I tried it. I got the driver from [http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=225&pcid=41](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=225&pcid=41) (version 1.19, 2017-10-31).

Comment: If you don't have internet access, how are you asking and reading here?

Comment: [An answer to *This device cannot start. (Code 10) - Gigaware USB - Serial Adapter*](https://superuser.com/questions/544485/this-device-cannot-start-code-10-gigaware-usb-serial-adapter/1001676#1001676) claims this is due to a fake PL2303 that never versions of the driver will not accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[This device cannot start. (Code 10) - Gigaware USB - Serial Adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/544485/this-device-cannot-start-code-10-gigaware-usb-serial-adapter)*.